# How to place a badge in lower right corner of an img in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I place a Bootstrap [badge](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges) in the lower right corner of an image?

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617660/how-to-place-a-badge-in-lower-right-corner-of-a-media-in-bootstrap) for placing bootstrap badges in the corner of media images, but can't convert that to make it work without a non-media image.

EDIT: Apologies for the lack of detail.  Here's an example with [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cME7/51/).

My goal is for the images to be on the same line next to each other, and the badges in the bottom right corner of the images.

Example:

```
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
  <span class="badge img-badge">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
  <span class="badge img-badge">4</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
  <span class="badge img-badge">5</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.image_with_badge_container {
   /*?*/
}

.img-badge {
   /*?*/
}
```

Comment: can you provide code or example where you want to put the badge

Comment: you need to customize the css .btn .badge {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    right: -20px;
    top: 15px;
}

Comment: @kindly provide the code through fiddle it wil be helpful to solve your question

Comment: update with fiddle. Sorry =(

Comment: See My demo page sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has a lot of views, so I thought I'd return and provide how I ended up solving this problem:

```css
.image_with_badge_container {
    display: inline-block; /* keeps the img with the badge if the img is forced to a new line */
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.badge-on-image {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px; /* position where you want it */
    left: 2px;
    padding: 3px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">7</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">3</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">7</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">3</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">7</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">3</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">7</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">3</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">7</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">2</span>
</div>
<div class="image_with_badge_container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64" />
    <span class="badge badge-on-image">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I like it

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
img {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;

  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="resources/images/Computer-lockup.png">
<span class="badge">4</span>
```

Now you have to position the badge according to your requirements.

Comment: It might be easier to set the distance using `bottom` and `right`, rather than `top` and `left` in this case.

Comment: yeah it is possible. actually i have positioned it according to my image.you may position your image according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
  .image_with_badge_container img+span.badge {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: -28px;
}
```

[DEMO PAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6cME7/58/)

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a non-media class image.

Comment: Now You can See Sir@43Tesseracts